# PHP: Target file path in fopen()

Tags: php, curl, fopen

I have a cURL download function as follows:

```
function down($url, $target){
    set_time_limit(0);
    $file = fopen(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . $target, 'w+');
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FILE           => $file,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 50,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)'
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    if($response === false) {
        throw new \Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl));
    }
    $response;
}
```

My script is in the following path:

> a-s/bootstrap/php/downloadscript.php

My aim is to store the downloaded file at:

> a-s/bootstrap/pronunciations/

When I run this script, it downloads the file to the `bootstrap` folder as expected (I haven't added the path to the `pronunciations` folder yet because I don't know how to) but the filename is prepended with the name of the folder. Thus, if the downloaded file is **word1.mp3**, the file saves as **bootstrapword1.mp3**. How can I make the file save with the original name without any prepend and in the right path?

Comment: Try to debug first... Copy the first argument of fipen function into a var_dump call to see what path is generating and you'll see why you are getting the bootstrap string in the filename

Comment: It looks like you're self-answering your question, so I agree with the downvote. This is nothing special, this is basic string manipulation and forgetting to check `var_dump(dirname(__FILE__))` to see if the string contains the required trailing slash (because it doesn't).

Comment: Didn't know it was wrong to self answer a question if the asker does indeed discover the answer on their own. It's not like the asker gains any reps by answering their own question so I don't know why they should be penalized but go ahead. Happy bullying. I am content I have the answer I needed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was the problem:

> $file = fopen(dirname(dirname(**FILE**)) . $target, 'w+');

Changing it to this fixed the issue:

> $file = fopen(dirname(dirname(**FILE**)) . "/pronunciations/" .
>   $target, 'w+');

Without the `/` in **fopen()**, the two strings were simply being concatenated hence the filename with the prepended directory name.

Answer (score -1):

A simpler solution is to use actual paths ;)

```
$file = fopen(__DIR__."/../pronunciations/".$target,'w+');
```

Note a couple of things:

- This uses the `__DIR__` constant, which indicates the current script's directory. It is equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)` but IMO clearer and more deliberate.
- `..` in a path means "parent directory". Yes, you can use this in a path! So for your sake I hope you've ensure that `$target` is a valid filename!!
- Obviously if the directory doesn't exist then it will fail. We can assume the current directory exists (otherwise how else is the file there?) and we can assume the parent directory (`..`) exists too. However, we *should not* assume that `pronunciations` exists...

  ```
  $dir = __DIR__."/../pronunciations";
  if( !file_exists($dir)) {
      mkdir($dir);
  }
  if( !is_dir($dir)) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Target directory not found");
  }
  ```

  Now you know the directory exists and you can attempt to write to it. Error handling is important!